# Left side of laser scan visualization on android gets weird

Tags: ros, laser-scan, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I'm trying to visualize the laser scan read on android. I am doing similar thing that can be found in many sample source codes. This means that I declare `VisualizationView laserView`, then I add two layers - laser scan and robot image by `laserView.addLayer(new LaserScanLayer("scan")); laserView.addLayer(new RobotLayer("base_link"))` and finally I execute it with nodeMainExecutor. The problem is that it display everything perfectly only on the right side of the robot, left side shows some kind of artifacts, remains from previous scans. The laser is hokuyo rug-04lx.

[image: laser scan n my device]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91836/left-side-of-laser-scan-visualization-on-android-gets-weird/) by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on 2013-10-17**:
Yeah. I described the problem but didn't ask the question. Do you know how to fix it? I was trying to manipulate the LaserScanLayer code but achieved nothing.

**Comment by [Tony10012](https://answers.ros.org/users/27331/tony10012/) on 2017-02-15**:
I have this problem and try to many methods to solve it,but achieved nothing.Can you solve it at the moment? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Effectively the artifacts seen are remainders of old scans. The solution was to update the limit of the vertex buffer according to the points received to only show the new data. This was fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/pull/252).

---

Originally posted by [Ernesto Corbellini](https://answers.ros.org/users/23887/ernesto-corbellini/) with karma: 101 on 2017-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0